# Using a vector of new and old names in tidyverse to select and rename columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to select columns and rename them based on the names of the columns which I keep in a separate dataframe.

This is the original dataset:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~year, ~country, ~series1, ~series2, 
  2003, "USA", 8, 5,
  2004, "USA", 9, 6, 
  2005, "USA", 11, 7, 
  2006, "USA", 10, 8
)
```

I want to select and rename two columns and I want to specify that like this:

```
specs <- tribble(
  ~old_name, ~new_name, 
  "country", "region",
  "series1", "gdp_growth"
)
```

I want this result:

```
expected_df <- tribble(
  ~region, ~gdp_growth,
  "USA", 8, 
  "USA", 9, 
  "USA", 11, 
  "USA", 10
)
```

This does not work:

```
df %>% 
  select(specs$new_name = specs$old_name)
```

> `Error: unexpected '=' in: "df %>%    select(specs$new_name ="`

Comment: Try `df %>% select(region = country, gdp_growth = series1)`?

Comment: That only works in this specific case, I would like that to work in general no matter what's in my `spec` dataframe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df %>%  
  select(specs$old_name) %>% 
  rename_with(~specs$new_name, specs$old_name)

#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   region gdp_growth
#>   <chr>       <dbl>
#> 1 USA             8
#> 2 USA             9
#> 3 USA            11
#> 4 USA            10
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
df %>% 
  select(specs$old_name) %>% set_names(specs$new_name)
```

Answer (score 3):

We could do

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
df %>% 
   select(!!! deframe(specs[2:1]))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  region gdp_growth
  <chr>       <dbl>
1 USA             8
2 USA             9
3 USA            11
4 USA            10
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```r
library(tidyverse)


df |>
  rename_with(.cols = specs$old_name, .fn = \(x) specs$new_name) |>
  select(!!!syms(specs$new_name))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   region gdp_growth
#>   <chr>       <dbl>
#> 1 USA             8
#> 2 USA             9
#> 3 USA            11
#> 4 USA            10
```

EDIT:

or another option:

```r
map2_dfc(specs$new_name, 
         specs$old_name, 
         \(new, old) select(df, !!sym(new) := !!sym(old)))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   region gdp_growth
#>   <chr>       <dbl>
#> 1 USA             8
#> 2 USA             9
#> 3 USA            11
#> 4 USA            10
```

Answer (score 2):

Two more similar but slightly different ways to those already proposed.

```
df %>% select(specs$old_name) %>% setNames(., specs$new_name)
```

OR

```
df %>% select(specs$old_name) %>% `colnames<-` (., specs$new_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

A base `R` option by matching the columns with the values from your dataframe like this:

```r
# Select columns
df = df[,2:3]
# Convert to dataframe isntead of tibble
df = as.data.frame(df)
specs = as.data.frame(specs)

names(df)[match(specs[,"old_name"], names(df))] = specs[,"new_name"]
df
#>   region gdp_growth
#> 1    USA          8
#> 2    USA          9
#> 3    USA         11
#> 4    USA         10
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>